# Golang client.pkg: How to execute a "list secret " under a resourceNames restriction with

Tags: go, kubernetes, rbac

The golang operator started writing an error.

`failed to list v1.Secret: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:operator-*****" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "namespace-name"`

The error appeared after we enabled restrictions on list secret (set resource Names).
Without restrictions, everything works fine.
I am not familiar with golang, but after looking at the source code, I came to the conclusion that the error occurs in this place

```
    if err := g.client.Get(ctx, client.ObjectKey{Name: tokens.Name, Namespace: g.namespace}, &tokens); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to query tokens")
```

Here is a more complete part of the code

```
package initgeneration

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    
    dynatracev1beta1 "github.com/Dynatrace/dynatrace-operator/src/api/v1beta1"
    "github.com/Dynatrace/dynatrace-operator/src/config"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/labels"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"
)


// InitGenerator manages the init secret generation for the user namespaces.

type InitGenerator struct {
    client        client.Client
    apiReader     client.Reader
    namespace     string
    canWatchNodes bool
    dynakubeQuery kubeobjects.DynakubeQuery
}
...

func (g *InitGenerator) createSecretConfigForDynaKube(ctx context.Context, dynakube *dynatracev1beta1.DynaKube, kubeSystemUID types.UID, hostMonitoringNodes map[string]string) (*standalone.SecretConfig, error) {
    var tokens corev1.Secret
    if err := g.client.Get(ctx, client.ObjectKey{Name: tokens.Name, Namespace: g.namespace}, &tokens); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.WithMessage(err, "failed to query tokens")
```

The Get method is used in the package "asus.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client " , when accessing the K8S API, it requests all the secrets and only then imposes a filter.
I need to get around this limitation
How to get secrets, how to access the K8S API through the client package with a restriction on resourceName?

Comment: Either you remove the resource name restriction so that you can access all secrets, or you only request specific secrets that match the resource name restriction. There's not really a middle ground here: either fix the RBAC, or fix your code.

Comment: I understand) . The question is which code or package to use to get certain secrets? My acquaintance with golang started just a week ago)

Comment: If you are using OperatorSDK or KubeBuilder, check this https://kubebyexample.com/learning-paths/operator-framework/operator-sdk-go/rbac-operator-authorization

Answer (score 1):

Controller-runtime client ( "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client") goes to its cache when receiving a request, and it updates the cache through the watch operation, i.e. it needs access to all secrets

The solution that helped: disable cache for secrets in "Options"
https://pkg.go.dev/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/manager#Options

via ClientDisableCacheFor

```
func (provider operatorManagerProvider) createOptions(namespace string) ctrl.Options {
    return ctrl.Options{
        Namespace:                  namespace,
        Scheme:                     scheme.Scheme,
        MetricsBindAddress:         metricsBindAddress,
        Port:                       operatorManagerPort,
        ...
        ClientDisableCacheFor: []client.Object{
            &corev1.Secret{},
        },
    }
}
```